# Identifying shorted capacitor on laptop motherboard

Tags: capacitor, short-circuit, laptop

**Background:**

My Asus U47A laptop stopped charging or running off the AC adapter. 
With the help of diagnostic tips on the internet, I found the culprit to be a faulty ceramic cap near the input jack on the motherboard.

One end of the cap goes to ground, the other seems to go the "gate" of an N-Channel Mosfet ([datasheet](http://www.rom.by/files/09n03.pdf)) just above it.

**Problem:**

I have removed the faulty cap, and I no longer have a short at the input jack... Now how do I determine the right capacitor as a replacement?

Also, is it likely that the faulty cap damaged another component or resulted from another faulty component?

Pic of the faulty cap
[image: asus u47a motherboard]

Comment: Repair questions are generally off topic on EE.SE so the question is likely to get closed. In any case it's probably just a simple decoupling capacitor - try something like an 0805 package 1uF cap rated at around twice the supply voltage or more. Whether or not it has affected anything else, it's impossible to tell, but probably not if it is straight across the power supply input. All you can really do is plug it back in and hope.

Comment: What's that ball of solder just above the capacitor and to the left of the transistor connected to? that looks a little suspicious.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I have some 0.47uF 50V caps on hand so I soldered it in place. The laptop is now charging, however it does not turn on either on battery or straight AC adaptor.

Comment: The solder ball was there beforehand. There seems to be a split in the circuit traces and the solder ball is connecting it. Looks weird to me too, but it's like that on both sides.